# Set options in the Stanford NLP Parser in Java

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use the Stanford NLP Parser to parse POS tagged data. Since my data is already tagged and tokenized I am trying to use the `setOptionFlags()` method to inform the parser about this like,

```
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
lp.setOptionFlags(new String[]{"-sentences", "newline", "-tokenized", "-tagSeparator", "_", "-tokenizerFactory", "edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer", "-tokenizerMethod", "newCoreLabelTokenizerFactory"});
```

However, I keep getting an exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown option: -sentences
```

I have searched online through the Javadocs provided and this is the way that it is done in their examples. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The options for tokenization, tag separator, etc. are not options for the parser, sensu stricto, but for the `DocumentPreprocessor` that is used to build input to the parser in the main method of `LexicalizedParser`. For the actual parser, the input is a list of tokens, and these are parsed.  Hence, you can't give these options as parser options with `setOptions()`.

If you've got a List of tokens, you can put them straight into the parser with this method in `LexicalizedParser`: `public Tree parse(List<? extends HasWord> lst)`.  If the items in the list implement `HasTag` (e.g., a `TaggedWord` or a `CoreLabel`) and have a non-null tag, then that will be used by the parser in parsing the sentence.

If you want to use a `DocumentPreprocessor` to split up text with tokenized tagged words, then you need to create a `DocumentPreprocessor` and then to set things up (a bit manually, sorry) with the methods like `setTagDelimiter(String s)`.